# Present Simple / Will

Tags: verbs

Should the Present Simple or Will be used in the following sentence? I'm referring to a future decision.

In my view, it doesn't matter what sport you ('ll) choose; the most important thing is that you ('ll) enjoy the sport you ('ll) do and that you ('ll) try your best to get better at it!

Comment: Can you show a bit more effort here.  It seems that your asking us to do a task, not answer a question.  What do you think is right? **Why**?

Answer (score 1):

Simple Present is for a general idea or proposition:

ADVICE:
In my view, it doesn't matter what sport you choose; the most important thing is that you enjoy the sport you do and that you try your best to get better at it!

As that is a general idea, the simple present is correct.

BUT, please bear this in mind:

Often, the will auxiliary should be used as in:
I'll leave now, not later.
I'll do the work now, not later.

Why? Because the present simple is usually for generalities when using an action verb:
I leave work everyday at five.

When you offer to do something or inform someone you plan to do something, use "will". Just leave that. I'll do that later.